# How to optimize pyOpenGL Icosahedron sphere? My code renders it in 2-3 fps with around 5000 polygons

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opengl, pyopengl

Here is my code for icosahedron generation, it creates a rotating shape with randomly colored triangles. The call is on the line 206.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import numpy as np
import ctypes

# Global variables
rotation_speed = -0.1  # Rotation speed (higher value = faster rotation)
fullscreen = False  # Fullscreen mode status (True or False)
rotation_axis = (0, 1, 0)  # Rotation axis (x, y, z)
initial_rotation_axis = (1, 0, 0)  # Initial rotation axis (x, y, z)
initial_rotation_angle = 90  # Initial rotation angle (degrees)

colors = [
    (1, 0, 0),  # Red
    (0, 1, 0),  # Green
    (0, 0, 1),  # Blue
    (1, 1, 0),  # Yellow
    (1, 0, 1),  # Magenta
    (0, 1, 1),  # Cyan
]

def create_icosphere(subdivisions, radius):
    from math import sqrt, atan2, pi, sin, cos

    def normalize(v):
        mag = sqrt(sum([x * x for x in v]))
        return [x / mag for x in v]

    def add_vertex(v):
        index = len(vertices)
        vertices.append(v)
        return index

    def get_middle_point(p1, p2):
        first_is_smaller = p1 < p2
        smaller_index = p1 if first_is_smaller else p2
        greater_index = p2 if first_is_smaller else p1
        key = (smaller_index, greater_index)

        if key in middle_point_cache:
            return middle_point_cache[key]

        vert1 = vertices[p1]
        vert2 = vertices[p2]
        middle = [(vert1[0] + vert2[0]) / 2, (vert1[1] + vert2[1]) / 2, (vert1[2] + vert2[2]) / 2]
        middle = normalize(middle)

        index = add_vertex(middle)
        middle_point_cache[key] = index
        return index

    vertices = []
    faces = []
    middle_point_cache = {}

    t = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0

    add_vertex(normalize([-1,  t,  0]))
    add_vertex(normalize([ 1,  t,  0]))
    add_vertex(normalize([-1, -t,  0]))
    add_vertex(normalize([ 1, -t,  0]))

    add_vertex(normalize([ 0, -1,  t]))
    add_vertex(normalize([ 0,  1,  t]))
    add_vertex(normalize([ 0, -1, -t]))
    add_vertex(normalize([ 0,  1, -t]))

    add_vertex(normalize([ t,  0, -1]))
    add_vertex(normalize([ t,  0,  1]))
    add_vertex(normalize([-t,  0, -1]))
    add_vertex(normalize([-t,  0,  1]))

    faces.extend([
        (0, 11, 5),
        (0, 5, 1),
        (0, 1, 7),
        (0, 7, 10),
        (0, 10, 11),

        (1, 5, 9),
        (5, 11, 4),
        (11, 10, 2),
        (10, 7, 6),
        (7, 1, 8),

        (3, 9, 4),
        (3, 4, 2),
        (3, 2, 6),
        (3, 6, 8),
        (3, 8, 9),

        (4, 9, 5),
        (2, 4, 11),
        (6, 2, 10),
        (8, 6, 7),
        (9, 8, 1),
    ])

    for _ in range(subdivisions):
        new_faces = []
        for face in faces:
            v1, v2, v3 = face

            a = get_middle_point(v1, v2)
            b = get_middle_point(v2, v3)
            c = get_middle_point(v3, v1)

            new_faces.extend([
                (v1, a, c),
                (v2, b, a),
                (v3, c, b),
                (a, b, c),
            ])

        faces = new_faces

    # Scale vertices by the radius
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        vertices[i] = [x * radius for x in vertices[i]]

    return vertices, faces


def draw_sphere_of_random_colored_triangles(subdivisions, radius):
    vertices, faces = create_icosphere(subdivisions, radius)
    vertices = np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float32)
    faces = np.array(faces, dtype=np.uint32)

    vertex_buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    index_buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer)
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, faces.nbytes, faces, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

    for i in range(len(faces)):
        color = colors[i % len(colors)]
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, [color[0] * 0.2, color[1] * 0.2, color[2] * 0.2, 1])
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, [color[0] * 0.8, color[1] * 0.8, color[2] * 0.8, 1])
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, [1, 1, 1, 1])
        glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 50)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ctypes.c_void_p(i * 3 * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_uint32)))

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

    glDeleteBuffers(1, [vertex_buffer])
    glDeleteBuffers(1, [index_buffer])


def toggle_fullscreen():
    global fullscreen
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    fullscreen = not fullscreen
    if fullscreen:
        pygame.display.set_mode(screen.get_size(), FULLSCREEN | DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    else:
        pygame.display.set_mode(screen.get_size(), DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

def main():
    global rotation_speed, rotation_axis, fullscreen, initial_rotation_axis, initial_rotation_angle
    pygame.init()
    display = (1440, 900)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

    camera_x, camera_y, camera_z = 0.0, 0.0, -5.0
    camera_angle = 45

    gluPerspective(camera_angle, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(camera_x, camera_y, camera_z)
    glRotatef(15, 1, 0, 0)

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)  # Enable OpenGL lighting
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)  # Enable a light source (Light0)

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, [-2, -2, 6, 2])  # Set the light position
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [1, 1, 1, 1])  # Set the light color
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, [1, 1, 1, 1])  # Set the specular light

    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)  # Disable color material

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_f:
                toggle_fullscreen()

        glRotatef(rotation_speed, rotation_axis[0], rotation_axis[1], rotation_axis[2])
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        draw_sphere_of_random_colored_triangles(4, 1.2)  # Draw a sphere with subdivisions and a radius of 1.2
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried using vbo and vao along with shaders, however it just crashed the program. The pyopengl version is 3.1.6 and all other libraries are latest versions. I also ran code profiler, the most time is taken by create_icosphere function and the loop in draw_sphere_of_random_colored_triangles function. Please help!

Expected behaviour: at least 30 fps at 5-6 subdivisions argument passed to draw_sphere_of_random_colored_triangles function.

Comment: Currently, you create and delete the vertex buffer in each frame. Create it once, upload the vertex data once. Then render it in each frame (without recreating any buffers)

Comment: You are recreating not just the vertex buffers and index buffers each frame, but also each vertices and faces. Of course it's slow like hell.